# Wrap an element with my own custom class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, x-editable

X-editable uses the default checkboxes as can be seen in [this](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#checklist) example.

What I want to do is wrap the template responsible for creating the checklist with my own class (`<div class="...`) that will take care of styling the elements as I want.

Looking at the [themes](https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/blob/master/src/js/themes.js) part on the source code did not help me a lot.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start. My idea was to find and manually add my class name to the part inside x-editable's sources where the <div> wrapper is being created, and I currently am at the process of finding it.

Comment: Why do you want to want to wrap it like this? This is essential knowing so you could get a good / relevant answer.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld because the idea was that I customize the popup that comes whenever you click an editable item in order to add my own animation on how it should appear and colors etc. So I have this in a my css the usual way `.class {...}`

Comment: Are you stuck with x-editable or could you use bootstrap instead?

Comment: I wanted to learn how to do it in x-editable but any solution that accomplishes what I want should be acceptable.  This is not for work or school, I was simply doing a smart table/form template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst way, probably, is by editing the source code. In this case the templates for the checklist are created in line 3225. So if you alter them depending on what you need it should be ok.